# How can I validate an attribute to be between various noncontinuous ranges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, range

I'm wanting to validate that my height attribute is within a bunch of different ranges.  So my attempt was something like what I did below... however this is incorrect.  How should this be done? Thanks!

```
validates :height, :numericality => { in: { 5020..5028, 5030..5038, 5040..5048, 5050..5058, 5060..5068, 5070..5078, 5080..5088, 5090..5098, 5100..5108, 5110..5118,
                                            6000..6008, 6010..6018, 6020..6028, 6030..6038, 6040..6048, 6050..6058, 6060..6068, 6070..6078, 6080..6088, 6090..6098, 6100..6108, 6110..6118,
                                            7000..7008, 7010..7018, 7020..7028, 7030..7038, 7040..7048, 7050..7058, 7060..7068, 7070..7078, 7080..7088, 7090..7098, 7100..7108, 7110..7118 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that in a custom [validate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate) method:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_HEIGHT_RANGES = [5020..5028, 5030..5038, 5040..5048, 5050..5058, 5060..5068, 5070..5078, 5080..5088, 5090..5098, 5100..5108, 5110..5118, 6000..6008, 6010..6018, 6020..6028, 6030..6038, 6040..6048, 6050..6058, 6060..6068, 6070..6078, 6080..6088, 6090..6098, 6100..6108, 6110..6118, 7000..7008, 7010..7018, 7020..7028, 7030..7038, 7040..7048, 7050..7058, 7060..7068, 7070..7078, 7080..7088, 7090..7098, 7100..7108, 7110..7118]
  validate :height_in_valid_range

  private

  def height_in_valid_range
    VALID_HEIGHT_RANGES.each do |range|
      unless range.include? height
        errors.add :height, "not in valid range"
        break
      end
    end
  end
end
```